# SASS simplify a mixin with prefixes

Tags: sass

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
@each $prefix in webkit moz ms o {

    -#{$prefix}-transition: all 1s linear;
}
transition: all 1s linear;
```

I hate redundancy and I would prefer if I could do it even simplier

**EDIT**:

Just to be clear. Im not looking for a method to implement transitions, what I want is a simplier code. In the example I give you see that I write 2 times the sale property. I would like to optimize this. Here an example of what I would be looking for (but **this is NOT valid SCSS**)

```
@each $prefix in "-webkit-", "-moz-", "-ms-", "-o-", "" {

    #{$prefix}transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you are evaluating 'redundancy'.. sometimes that is the opposite of 'complexity' - one line for The_One_Who_Follows_The_Spec, and one @each for Others_Who_Dont (a list that will be disappearing over time).. It's a better separation of responsibilities to separate them. Also, subjectively, nothing below is any clearer in stating its intent, nor more concise than your version - I'm surprised you're looking to 'improve' it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Transition isn't the only property that needs prefixes. As vendors add support, you can stop including the prefixes. If you abstract each part of your mixin, your code will be more maintainable in the long run.

```
$default-prefixes: webkit moz ms o;

@mixin build-prefix-values($property, $value, $prefixes: $default-prefixes) {
    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
        -#{$prefix}-#{$property}: #{$value};
    }
    #{$property}: #{$value};
} 

@mixin transition($property: all, $delay: 1s, $timing: linear) {
    $value: $property $delay $timing;
    // use default prefixes
    @include build-prefix-values('transition', $value);
}

// using defaults of 'all' '1s' and 'linear'
p {
    @include transition();
}

// using custom values
.fast {
    @include transition('height', '.1s', 'ease', '0');
}
```

Now let's say you want to write a @mixin for `border-radius` where `webkit` is the only prefix you need.

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
    $prefixes: webkit;
    @include build-prefix-values('border-radius', $radius, $prefixes);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address my question. This code uses the same instructions as my code: first using a loop for the prefixes and then writing again the instruction without the prefix.

Comment: Focus less on optimizing 3 lines of code and more on making it reusable for the lifetime of this project and the next. My answer eliminates redundancy by declaring the prefixes **once** and declaring the loop **once** so you can reuse it over and over. When every major browser supports every CSS3 property without a prefix, you'll be able to edit **one** place **once** to eliminate all the extra cruft. If a new browser takes the market by storm and you have to add another prefix, you only have to make **one** change. This makes your code easier to read and maintain, thus simpler.

Comment: You are disregarding the nature of my question, and assuming what I want to achieve with it. Im not asking how to build mixins for css3 properties. Im asking how to optimize certain code, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unquote` [sass function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method) to unquote each prefix. I mean:

```
@each $prefix in "-webkit-", "-moz-", "-ms-", "-o-", "" {
    #{unquote($prefix)}transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

I think is the cleaner way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

In Bourbon there are mixin like that you have (by the way, I recommend to use it when you need a lot of similar things): http://thoughtbot.com/bourbon/#transitions

And its code: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/functions/_transition-property-name.scss

On this basis, you have more or less optimal solution.

Comment: It's an interesting links, but it doesnt really answer my question. This link ( https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_prefixer.scss ) is really what interests me of Bourbon, but as you can see, its also redundant. Im looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: Yeah, there are easily 10 "you could use x" (e.g., compass) answers to this but that's not what the OP was requesting...

Comment: @JustinMaxwell, thank you for your comment. In my answer, I gave a link to a similar code in the bourbon. There were approximately the same solution as the OP has. Based on this, I concluded that it is hardly possible to optimize more. That was my answer.