# Using string concatenation for properties in Sass

Tags: sass

The following mixin Sass code works just fine:

```
@mixin test($attr, $radius) {
    hey :blah + $attr;
}
```

I can set the `$attr` parameter to `foo` and the output will be

```
hey: blahfoo
```

But the following code doesn't work:

```
@mixin test($attr, $radius) {
    hey + $attr :blah;
}
```

It just throws a syntax error.  How can I do string concatenation for the property names, just like I can do for the values?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752746/sass-simplify-a-mixin-with-prefixes

Comment: Ah great, I assumed this had been addressed before, but my googling skills could not discover this one.  Thanks!